# How to have persistent storage for a PYPI package

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi, python-packaging

I have a pypi package called [collectiondbf](https://pypi.org/project/collectiondbf/) which connects to an API with a user entered API key. It is used in a directory to download files like so:

```sh
python -m collectiondbf [myargumentshere..]
```

I know this should be basic knowledge, but I'm really stuck on the question:

**How can I save the keys users give me in a meaningful way so that they do not have to enter them every time?**

I would like to use the following solution using a `config.json` file, but how would I know the location of this file if my package will be moving directories?

Here is how I would like to user it but obviously it won't work since the working directory will change

```py
import json
if user_inputed_keys:
    with open('config.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump({'api_key': api_key}, f)
```

Comment: Ask users to store the API key in an environment variable instead of passing it via command line arguments. From a security perspective this is also a lot preferable compared to storing it anywhere on disk.

Comment: Thanks @ksbg I do already have that as an option. I just thought there must also be a way to store it for them?

Comment: the user home dir is probably your best bet, something like `.mypkg/.api`. `import os
print(os.path.expanduser('~'))`

Comment: I don't see any advantage of storing the api value on an environment variable, quite the opposite in fact.

Comment: I agree with @PedroLobito that a local hidden file is a good first cut, but make sure to make it RW by your user only. Just do `ls -l ~/.ssh` on a linux machine and you are likely to see your private ssh key there. If that freaks the user out (it freaks me out), then selinux or apparmour or some other operating system level of protection is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most common operating systems have the concept of an application directory that belongs to every user who has an account on the system. This directory allows said user to create and read, for example, config files and settings.

So, all you need to do is make a list of all distros that you want to support, find out where they like to put user application files, and have a big old `if..elif..else` chain to open the appropriate directory.

---

Or use [`appdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/), which does exactly that already:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import json
import appdirs

CONFIG_DIR = Path(appdirs.user_config_dir(appname='collectiondbf'))  # magic
CONFIG_DIR.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

config = CONFIG_DIR / 'config.json'
if not config.exists():
  with config.open('w') as f:
    json.dumps(get_key_from_user(), f)
with config.open('r') as f:
  keys = json.load(f)  # now 'keys' can safely be imported from this module
```

Comment: Wow thank you Arne! This is exactly what I was looking for. I hope it will show up in the search results for others looking for a solution for this.